# aiohttp set_cookies doesn't set cookies

Tags: python, cookies, aiohttp

I have this view:

```
async def accept_token(request):
    resp = web.Response(text='cookies were set')
    resp.set_cookie('name',
                    'value,
                    path='/',
                    max_age=3600)
    return resp
```

But I see cookies only in Response Cookies in Firefox, Cookie storage is empty.
Setting CORS headers doesn't help

```
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'] = 'true'
    resp.headers['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'X-Server-Header'
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be with [samesite cookie policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite), you need to add `SameSite=none` to the cookie
(Support appeared in aiohttp 3.7.0 release 24 Oct 2020)

So with `aiohttp>=3.7.0` use next code

```
resp.set_cookie(... , samesite='none')
```